# Как происходит обработка данных в игре, когда сама игра закрыта?

Tags: unity3d

Есть много игр, в которых некоторые вещи могут происходить без участия пользователя. Например, Clash of Clans, где золото и эликсир могут накапливатся даже тогда, когда ты не играешь, а потом ты просто заходишь и забираешь их. Как работает эта система? Можно ссылки на какие-нибудь статьи? Просто я даже не знаю, что именно мне гуглить, так как ничего в этой теме не понимаю. Хочу добавить такую возможность для игры на юнити.

Comment: С накоплением чего либо очень просто. Достаточно знать скорость накопления и время, прошедшее с момента окончания игры. В момент когда вы входите опять в игру, можно рассчитать сколько за это время должно было набраться

Answer (score 1):

Большинство таких игр - онлайн игры. Все их данные обрабатываются на сервере. Вы замечали что они требуют интернета?

Comment: да, я замечал, но не понимаю, как это работает. Я знаю, что это обрабатывается на сервере, но как это работает?

Comment: @УмарМашуков Вам в принципе верно ответили, Вам необходимо прочитать про клиент-серверную архитектуру, это относится не только к играм, но и ко многому другому по.